# Firebase firestore query returning old data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am running a query in `react-native` and having an issue that the data returned is old.

```
var query = firebase.firestore().collection('rooms')
    .where('roomName', '==', roomName).where('archived', '==', false)
    .get().then((result) => {
      console.log('find result')
      console.log(result)
```

Is there anything I can add to the above query in order to ensure the data is retrieved from server and not cache?

Comment: How are you able to determine that it's "old"?  What exactly are you observing, and how is it different than what you expect?

Comment: By comparing the logged result document data. Compared to the live data in Firestone

Comment: Does your device have a working internet connection, or is it pulling results from local cache because it's offline?

Comment: Yes I’m getting that in simulator which is connected to internet

Comment: @StuartM The reason Doug is asking these questions is that a plain `get()` call on a device with active internet connection **should** be getting the latest data from the server already. So what you're seeing is unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yeah I have a bunch of other queries that do the same and work ok

Comment: this happing with me also, when i run my query on firebase console it return new data but when my android device it return old data, some document even deleted still firebase return in my android

Comment: does this link help? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#presence

Comment: same problem here: i closed the IDE, restarted the computer and it works again for me: I got the updated data from Firestore.